# What type of cache better to use to improve performance of website?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, high-load

I have high-load informative website with **10 000+** hits/day. It was rewritten on `Symfony 2 Framework` with `Doctrine2 ORM`. Site have heavy informative pages, each load on development server 0.5 - 1.5 seconds approximately. Note, that it time on *development server*, so it has minimal load.

I know there are many cache providers such as Varnish, Memcached, APC, HTTP, etc... Please, suggest me on what layer (*DB*, *HTTP*, etc...) and what type of cache better to use for improve performance of this site?

Comment: All depends in what you want to cache, and how frequently you'll need to refresh the cache, and thousands of other factors.... there is no best answer to such an open-ended question

Comment: @MarkBaker I know that the load on the database is minimal. I have heavy pages with lot of info, and it heavily rendering. My goal is to use some cache that allows the site to withstand a load. But I don't know what cache to choose

Comment: So start by asking yourself "what do you want to cache?"

Comment: @MarkBaker I think I need to cache whole static page, that already rendered once, and then show to all users this cached page until it will be outdated

Comment: @Victor The first thing you would do is benchmarking. The symfony toolbar helps you a bit with it, there are many ways to properly find out where the time is actually lost. You don't really know it apparently. Then you can decide what you really want to cache. it is hard to suggest caching if you don't know where the problem is.

Comment: @Koalabaerchen, Thanks, I try to benchmarking my app with symfony toolbar first

Comment: @Victor : For HTTP Caching, you should take a look at [FOSHttpCacheBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSHttpCacheBundle/)

Comment: 10k hits a day sounds like a lot but it's 0.116 requests per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Mark said in the comment, "*there is no best answer to such an open-ended question*".
At first, let's find the *what*: which component is the system bottleneck, DB, HTTP response, javascript...?

And in each component, there are other questions:

- **DB**: Which queries slow the system down (Hint: using Log Slow Query)? Can we refator those? (This is often the key factor, given that it's informative website) What is the result of [MySQL Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) or other alternatives?
- **HTTP response**: Does it take unreasonably much time to transport rendered content to client machine? (Hint: using Web Developer Tools or even cUrl). Does it load the static files over and over again without utilizing the HTTP cache? Does using [Nginx caching](https://serversforhackers.com/editions/2014/09/09/nginx-caching/) help?
- **Javascript**: Are there any scripts that block browser from rendering the page? Are there any errors caused by conflicts of scripts (which will add up the waiting time for sure)?

....

Let's have the checklist, which list those questions <--> answers.
The answer for "*what type of cache better to use for improve performance of this site*" **TOTALLY DEPENDS** on those.

Somewhere to reference:

- [Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/)
- [MySQL Log Slow Query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html)
- [Xdebug Profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)
- [Speed up your PHP Application with Zend Opcache](http://fideloper.com/install-zend-opcache)

And I recommend a very very good book: [Scale PHP Application](https://www.scalingphpbook.com/), in which you can learn real use cases, how to debug, how to profile..